# Finding the element in DropDown in C# (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to find the field name "userPick", and then select the first item from the drop down list.

The Html code behind this:

```
<div class="fullRow">
<label for="userPick" class="fieldLabel90right">User:</label>
<select id="userPick" name="userPick" class="selectfont" size="1"   onchange="editIbUser(this)">
<option value="0">--- Select a user to edit ---</option>
<option value="1623" size="small" selected="">IIII, OOOOO  (IOOP78 - Email: jjj@ff.com)</option>
<option value="1620" size="small">JJJ, AKU  (aroy - Email: lll@hh.com)</option>
<option value="1625" size="small">LLL, KK  (LLL90 - Email: kl@h.com) </option>
<option value="1626" size="small">ROY, ADRIJA  (AR8456 - Email: rry@gm.com) </option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Sort by Email Address" name="btnSort"  onclick="userSort('name')" style="width: 180px; line-height: 1px;"/>
</div>
```

The C# code that I am using is:

```
var User = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("userPick"));
var firstitem1 = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("option"))[1];
firstitem1.Click();
```

I have also used:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
User=wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("userPick")));
var firstitem1 = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("option"))[1];
firstitem1.Click();
```

And this as well:

```
var User = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("userPick"));
var firstitem1 = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("option"))[1];
IJavaScriptExecutor js1 = Driver.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js1.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", firstitem1);
```

The problem I am facing is, its not giving any exception and it is simply overlooking this field name and giving me successful Test.

I need to find the field name userPick, but it seems it is unable to find that. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `SelectElement` for dropdown as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var User=wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("userPick")));
var select = new SelectElement(User);
select.SelectByIndex(1);
```

Or

```
 select.SelectByValue("1623");
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @Adrija you welcome..To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I am doing exactly the same thing you are asking me to, after I am clicking the arrow, it is giving me "You have found the answer to be useful".

Comment: @Adrija its not arrow dude. it is a check mark which appears below the arrow with white empty looks..when you will click on it. It will be toggle to green colour, then the answer will seems to be accepted... try it..

Comment: Now is it okay, I clicked the Tick, it turned green @Saurabh

Comment: @Adrija now you got it.. please review your all questions and accept the correct answer which will help to you and others.. :)